# из ASCII -> UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

Проблема какая-то не понятна.
использую следующий код:

```
$track = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($track, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $track);
```

Когда название на латинице, все хорошо. На кирилице крякозябры или пустота.
Как отобразить нормально киррилицу?
на опенсервере все гуд,на хосте проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mb_detect_encoding($track, mb_detect_order(), true)==null)
{ $track = mb_convert_encoding($track, "utf-8", "windows-1251"); }
$track = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($track, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $track);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть что-то типа:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По комменту:

- Посмотрите в phpinfo(); какие кодировки установлены на сервере (в разделе iconv).
- попробуйте такой формат:

  $convertedText = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($text));

---

Попробуйте на проблемную страницу/шаблон, в самый верх, добавить header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); и посмотрите, как и что.

И посмотрите, что ваша страница/шаблон были сохранены без BOM.

*Если обнаружится, что было с BOM, то сохраните без BOM и посмотрите без header, что получается, а потом уж, если надо, то поставьте header на сохраненное без BOM.

Comment: Это уже есть и сохранено без ВОМ :(

Comment: header стоит уже?

Comment: Да, хеадер стоит. может еще есть варианты?

Comment: iconv
iconv support enabled
iconv implementation glibc
iconv library version 2.17
Directive Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding no value no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value no value
iconv.output_encoding no value no value

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/wrW9vFk/Untitled.png

Comment: Тогда непонятно, из какой и в какую Вы преобразовываете.

Comment: У меня VPS. Впервые в жизни. я не знаю, что к чему)) что написать в ТП,плодскажите?

Comment: Думается, что сначала надо бы самому разобраться - может быть конфигурациия, апач/nginx что где, и посмотреть вообще - у Вас же что-то отображается где-то, и если проблема СО ВСЕМ киррилическим, тогда так  и пишите, если от них все зависит.

Comment: посмотрел на опенсервере пхпинфо(), раздел иконв, она точно такая-же, как и на впс.

Comment: на опенсервере работает, на впс нет))))))))) чудеса.

Comment: Посмотрите, что у Вас с кэшем на vps  - возможно, в нем причина - да и не чудеса это - это обычно часто бывает - на локале и рабочем всегда есть затыки, как правило.

Comment: В общем проблема оказалась не в отсуствии кодировок на сервере, а в том, что mb_detect_order() не определяет искаженную windows-1251 и возвращает пустоту.


Решение нашел такое, костыльное, зато всё, что прилитает - показывает.
if (mb_detect_encoding($track, mb_detect_order(), true)==null){
$track = mb_convert_encoding($track, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
}
$track = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($track, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $track);